# How to delete an NA (empty) vertex

Tags: r, igraph, na, vertex

I'm making an (undirected) social network plot with the `igraph` package, which I've practised with a subset of my data. For this the vertex have to be in two columns and that way all associations are shown. however sometimes a vertex (individual, I'm working with animals) is encountered alone, with no associations. so this animal will be in the left column and on the right column there is nothing, an empty cell.

However in the `igraph` package R thinks that "NA"/nothing is an animals ID so it makes a vertex out of it. In my subset I had solved this problem like this:

```
y <- data.frame(data$ID1, data$ID2)
```

*ID1 and 2 are the codes from the pit-tag readers to recognize the individual animals. its basically their name.*

```
graph.data.frame(y, directed=FALSE)
```

*I'm calling this graph: net*

```
net <- graph.data.frame(y, directed=FALSE)
net <- delete_vertices(net, "")
```

so in the code shown above the empty values, where nog animal ID was filled in, are deleted from the graph. I was thrilled I achieved this, but as I said it was in a subset of my data which I had already manually edited.

For the whole dataset, I had to wrangle the data. because the animals were observed in larger groups, so I had 8 columns with animal ID which were all associated together. this had to be reformed to two columns in which all possible permutations on a single location was covered (so for a group of 4 animals I needed the combination 1-2; 1-3; 1-4; 2-3; 2-4 and 3-4 and groups vary from 1 to 8 animals(vertexes)). I've done this with the `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages (and help). when there's no value in one of the columns (because it was an individual being by itself) R says:

> ```
>  Warning messages:  
>  1: In graph.data.frame(y, directed = FALSE) :  
>     In `d' `NA' elements were replaced with string "NA"  
>  2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "NA") :  
>     invalid factor level, NA generated
> ```

So in my opinion it replaces the empty space with `NA`, which is also what it show when it tell R to show the new wrangled data. however the trick with remove vertices doesn't work anymore. it keeps saying `"invalid vertex name"`. I've tried it with `""`, with `"NA"`, `NA`, `"<NA>"` and everything logical I could think of but I cannot seem to solve this.

I'm hoping its an error which is easily solvable with a different " or , or something. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why not remove these rows with missing from `y` prior to creating the graph. If required you can add the nodes in, with no edges, later.

Comment: thank you for your response. However the dataset is quite big so if i have to add in all these extra nodes afterwards it is going to be a lot of work. I'm keeping it in mind as a plan B though; in case i really can's solve it.

Comment: cynthia; it shouldn't be that difficult. If your data is like `y <- data.frame(ID1 = c(letters[1:5]), ID2=c(letters[6:8], c(NA, NA)))` you grab an indicator of missing `idx = is.na(y$ID2)`, get nodes without edges `orph = y$ID1[idx]`, form the graph with no missing `g = graph.data.frame(y[!idx, ], directed=FALSE)` then add in the other nodes `g = g + add_vertices(g, length(orph), attr=list(name=orph))`. If this doesn't represent your data can you try an create a small example as I did for creating `y`.

Comment: thank you so much! I thought i had to find the non linked nodes manually (from my excell file) but this makes much more sense! I got this working for a small subset of my data so i'm going to try it on the whole thing now. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If you get something working please consider writing an answer (with small reproducible example please)

Comment: I still need to clean up my code a bit, but i'll definetly post the part relating to my question here in a week or so. hopefully it'll be helpfull if someone encounters the same problem.